# Equality in COQ for enumerated types

Tags: coq

I have a finite enumerated type (say T) in COQ and want to check elements for equality. This means, I need a function

```
bool beq_T(x:T,y:T)
```

The only way I managed to define such a function, is with a case by case analysis. This results in lots of match statements and looks very cumbersome. Therefore, I wonder if there is not a simpler way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even simpler: `Scheme Equality for ...` generates two functions returning respectively a boolean and a sumbool.

Answer (score 2):

The bad news is that the program that implements `beq_T` must necessarily consist of a large match statement on both of its arguments. The good news is that you can automatically generate/synthesize this program using Coq's *tactic language*. For example, given the type:

```
Inductive T := t0 | t1 | t2 | t3.
```

You can define `beq_T` as follows. The first two `destruct` tactics synthesize the code necessary to match on both `x` and `y`. The `match` tactic inspects the branch of the match that it is in, and depending on whether `x = y`, the tactic either synthesises the program that returns `true` or `false`.

```
Definition beq_T (x y:T) : bool.
  destruct x eqn:?;
  destruct y eqn:?;
  match goal with 
  | _:x = ?T, _:y = ?T |- _ => exact true
  | _ => exact false
  end.
Defined.
```

If you want to see the synthesized program, run:

```
Print beq_T.
```

Thankfully, Coq already comes with a tactic that does almost what you want. It is called `decide equality`. It automatically synthesizes a program that decides whether two elements of a type `T` are equal. But instead of just returning a boolean value, the synthesized program returns a proof of the (in)equality of the two elements.

```
Definition eqDec_T (x y:T) : {x = y} + {x <> y}.
  decide equality.
Defined.
```

With that program synthesized, it is easy to implement `beq_T`.

```
Definition beq_T' {x y:T} : bool := if eqDec_T x y then true else false.
```